# How to prevent a drag action to affect the childrens of a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My problem is: I have a MovieClip (`obj`) that users can drag to both sides to navigate, the code I use for this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var destination: Point = new Point();
var dragging: Boolean = false;
var speed: Number = 10;
var offset: Point = new Point();
var bounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdrag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
obj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, followmouse);

function startdrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
    offset.x = obj.mouseX * obj.scaleX;
    dragging = true;
}

function stopdrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
    dragging = false;
}

function followmouse(e: Event): void {
    if (obj) {
        if (dragging) {
            destination.x = mouseX;
        }

        obj.x -= (obj.x - (destination.x - offset.x)) / speed;

        if (obj.x > bounds.left) {
            obj.x = bounds.left;
        }

        if (obj.x < -obj.width + bounds.right) {
            obj.x = -obj.width + bounds.right;
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good, the problem comes up when I put some clickable elements inside that MovieClip (`obj`), here are the code for the clickable elements:

```
objA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, objATrigger);
objB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, objBTrigger);
objC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, objCTrigger);

function objATrigger(event: MouseEvent): void {
    MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
}

function objBTrigger(event: MouseEvent): void {
    MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
}

function objCTrigger(event: MouseEvent): void {
    MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
}
```

The problem is: When I drag the MovieClip (`obj`) there is a conflict with the event, when release the mouse after the drag, the event `Click` of MovieClips inside the MovieClip (`obj`) is fired, how can I fix this? They should only be triggered when there is no drag action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I handle dragging a parent that has clickable children.  The benefit of this method, is that you don't need to do anything to the children (no extra conditions in their click handlers etc), the click event simply doesn't reach them.

You can also hopefully gleam some efficiency tips from the code/comments below:

```
var wasDragged:Boolean = false;
var dragThreshold:Point = new Point(10,10); 
// ^ how many pixels does it need to move before it's considered a drag
//this is good especially on touchscreens as it's easy to accidentally drag the item a couple pixels when clicking.

var dragStartPos:Point = new Point(); //to store drag origin point to calculate whether a drag occured
var dragOffset:Point = new Point(); //to track the gap between the mouse down point and object's top left corner

obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdrag);
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dragClick, true); //listen on the capture phase of the event. 

//the only reason we listen for click on the draggable object, is to cancel the click event so it's children don't get it
function dragClick(e:Event):void {
    //if we deemed it a drag, stop the click event from reaching any children of obj
    if(wasDragged) e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

function startdrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
    //reset all dragging vars
    wasDragged = false;
    dragStartPos.x = obj.x;
    dragStartPos.y = obj.y;

    //set the offset so the object doesn't jump when first clicked
    dragOffset.x = stage.mouseX - obj.x;
    dragOffset.y = stage.mouseY - obj.y;

    //only add the mouse up listener AFTER the mouse down
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
    //mouse_move is more efficient that enter_frame, and only listen for it when dragging
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, followmouse); 
}

function stopdrag(e:MouseEvent = null): void {
    //remove the dragging specific listeners
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, followmouse); 
}

function followmouse(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (obj) {
        //do what you need to move the object
        obj.x = stage.mouseX - dragOffset.x;
        obj.y = stage.mouseY - dragOffset.y;

        //check if the obj moved far enough from the original position to be considered a drag
        if(!wasDragged 
            && (Math.abs(obj.x - dragStartPos.x) > dragThreshold.x
            || Math.abs(obj.y - dragStartPos.y) > dragThreshold.y)
        ){
            wasDragged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don`t know if this is the best approach, but it was possible to check using the code below:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setmousepos);
brose_trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, broseTrigger);
denso_trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, densoTrigger);
honda_trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, hondaTrigger);

var mousePos: Point = new Point();

function setmousepos(e:MouseEvent): void {
    mousePos.x = mouseX;
}

function broseTrigger(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if(mousePos.x == mouseX){
        MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
    }
}

function densoTrigger(event:MouseEvent): void {
    if(mousePos.x == mouseX){
        MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
    }
}

function hondaTrigger(event:MouseEvent): void {
    if(mousePos.x == mouseX){
        MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
    }
}
```

When `MOUSE_DOWN` event is triggered, I store the `mouse.x` position in a variable, after that in the `MOUSE_UP` event, I compare the stored position with the actual position, if equals, TÃDÃ!

Answer (score 0):

Do add condition in objATrigger function to check if dragging is false

```
function objATrigger(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if(!MovieClip(root).dragging){
        MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, I've traced the variable and it returns `false`

Comment: Try changing addEventListener to : objA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objATrigger);

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: I thought to implement a time counter, after X seconds, however I do not really know how to do this

Comment: comment code inside movieclip and just add when you finished dragging…
function stopdrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
    dragging = false;
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Main");
}

Comment: This doesn't work, because the parent's `MOUSE_UP` listener will fire before the child's `CLICK` listener, so the `dragging` variable is reset back to false when the CLICK handler runs.    If listening for `MOUSE_DOWN` on the child, the child's `MOUSE_DOWN` will run before the parent's (so dragging hasn't been set the true yet). It would work if the parent's MOUSE_DOWN listener was listening on the capture phase