# After end of MouseMove or drag event menu keeping from release menu items

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, onmouseup

I am having a problem with draggable menu including menu button items.
At the end of drag operation (when I lift my finger from the screen) a button sub item works because of its MOUSE_UP code.

I need drag end drop my menu. After drop menu button items listeners should start for release (MOUSE_UP). How can I separete them?

I read some similar messages but I couldnt solve my problem.

My code:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragStart); 
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop); 
function dragStart(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,0,500,0)); 
}
function dragStop(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,0,500,0)); 
}
```

Thanks..

[My sample file is here](http://1e1ders.net/SliderButtons.rar)

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Thanks null; I added my code in my question message.

Comment: So your problem is that sub-items get a `MOUSE_UP` from parent menu? Or vice-versa? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes. As you said www0z0k, all sub items are buttons having MOUSE_UP functions. Each button infact same mc but includes are different. 'this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, BTN); function BTN(e:MouseEvent):void { var b=MovieClip(this.parent).parent.parent["Liste"+(root as MovieClip).ListeNo][int(this.name.split("BTN")[1])]; (root as MovieClip).sultan.eklenenNo=b; (root as MovieClip).BTNswitchCase(b); } '

Comment: I think you're basically asking the same question as this one I answered a few days ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38531688/1457439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:**
I was getting it wrong. I'd suggest switching a flag in the parent clip when it is dragged and ignore `MOUSE_UP` events in children if it is `true`.

In the parent:

```
var dragging:Boolean = false;

function dragStart(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,0,500,0));
    dragging = true;
}
function dragStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragStart);
    dragging = false;
}
```

In `subItem`:

```
function BTN(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(!(parent as MovieClip).dragging){
        trace("I'm a button: "+this+" Did you hit me when you sliding?");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks www0z0k, I ll research e.stopImmediatePropagation now.

Comment: Thats fine. It works. Thanks www0z0k. Thanks BadFeelingAboutThis too. I try to use e.stopImmediatePropagation() but I didnt achieve tis :(

Comment: Hi  www0z0k, another problem exist now. My each touch on the screen only move function works. Sub item buttons dosnt work despite small touching on the mobile phone screen.

Comment: @ErkanÇamyar does it seem to happen because finger tap always produces a small move?

Comment: Yes you are right @www0z0k . Deffinetely small movement is the reason.

Comment: I solved small movement problem with a simple trick. I used a counter working during drag operation. When mouse up if counter is higher than a small value (limit value) dragging is equal to true. Otherwise false. Thanks @ www0z0k